# Как найти ключ шифрования если есть оба файла? (вирус)

Tags: шифрование, криптография, petya

У меня получилось так, что есть старые копии файлов, и такие, которые не менялись, а так же есть шифрованые вирусом копии. Можно ли вычислить алгоритм и "ключ" шифрования? Вирус скорее всего petya.c (розовый шрифт на чёрном с $300, атака 27.06 в 14:00)

Можно ли определить шифр, какие бывают шифры?

Приведу короткий файл нешифрованую версию потом шифрованую

```
000:  2F 2F 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   //--------------
010:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   ----------------
020:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   ----------------
030:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   ----------------
040:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   ----------------
050:  0D 0A 2F 2F 20 3C 61 75 │ 74 6F 2D 67 65 6E 65 72   ♪◙// <auto-gener
060:  61 74 65 64 3E 0D 0A 2F │ 2F 20 20 20 20 20 DD F2   ated>♪◙//     Эт
070:  EE F2 20 EA EE E4 20 F1 │ EE E7 E4 E0 ED 20 EF F0   от код создан пр
080:  EE E3 F0 E0 EC EC EE E9 │ 2E 0D 0A 2F 2F 20 20 20   ограммой.♪◙//
090:  20 20 C8 F1 EF EE EB ED │ FF E5 EC E0 FF 20 E2 E5     Исполняемая ве
0A0:  F0 F1 E8 FF 3A 32 2E 30 │ 2E 35 30 37 32 37 2E 33   рсия:2.0.50727.3
0B0:  36 31 35 0D 0A 2F 2F 0D │ 0A 2F 2F 20 20 20 20 20   615♪◙//♪◙//
0C0:  C8 E7 EC E5 ED E5 ED E8 │ FF 20 E2 20 FD F2 EE EC   Изменения в этом
0D0:  20 F4 E0 E9 EB E5 20 EC │ EE E3 F3 F2 20 EF F0 E8    файле могут при
0E0:  E2 E5 F1 F2 E8 20 EA 20 │ ED E5 EF F0 E0 E2 E8 EB   вести к неправил
0F0:  FC ED EE E9 20 F0 E0 E1 │ EE F2 E5 20 E8 20 E1 F3   ьной работе и бу
100:  E4 F3 F2 20 EF EE F2 E5 │ F0 FF ED FB 20 E2 20 F1   дут потеряны в с
110:  EB F3 F7 E0 E5 0D 0A 2F │ 2F 20 20 20 20 20 EF EE   лучае♪◙//     по
120:  E2 F2 EE F0 ED EE E9 20 │ E3 E5 ED E5 F0 E0 F6 E8   вторной генераци
130:  E8 20 EA EE E4 E0 2E 0D │ 0A 2F 2F 20 3C 2F 61 75   и кода.♪◙// </au
140:  74 6F 2D 67 65 6E 65 72 │ 61 74 65 64 3E 0D 0A 2F   to-generated>♪◙/
150:  2F 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   /---------------
160:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   ----------------
170:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   ----------------
180:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D   ----------------
190:  2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D │ 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 2D 0D   ---------------♪
1A0:  0A 0D 0A 6E 61 6D 65 73 │ 70 61 63 65 20 55 6B 72   ◙♪◙namespace 
1B0:  50 6F 73 68 74 61 57 65 │ 62 43 74 72 6C 2E 43 6F   Co
1C0:  6E 74 72 6F 6C 73 20 7B │ 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 0D 0A   ntrols {♪◙    ♪◙
1D0:  20 20 20 20 70 75 62 6C │ 69 63 20 70 61 72 74 69       public parti
1E0:  61 6C 20 63 6C 61 73 73 │ 20 43 69 72 63 75 6C 61   al class Circula
1F0:  72 20 7B 0D 0A 20 20 20 │ 20 20 20 20 20 70 72 6F   r {♪◙        pro
200:  74 65 63 74 65 64 20 53 │ 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 57 65   tected System.We
210:  62 2E 55 49 2E 57 65 62 │ 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 73   b.UI.WebControls
220:  2E 4C 61 62 65 6C 20 45 │ 72 72 6F 72 4C 61 62 65   .Label ErrorLabe
230:  6C 3B 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 │ 20 20 20 20 70 72 6F 74   l;♪◙        prot
240:  65 63 74 65 64 20 4D 69 │ 63 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2E   ected Microsoft.
250:  52 65 70 6F 72 74 69 6E │ 67 2E 57 65 62 46 6F 72   Reporting.WebFor
260:  6D 73 2E 52 65 70 6F 72 │ 74 56 69 65 77 65 72 20   ms.ReportViewer
270:  72 76 43 69 72 63 75 6C │ 61 72 4C 69 73 74 3B 0D   rvCircularList;♪
280:  0A 20 20 20 20 7D 0D 0A │ 7D 0D 0A                  ◙    }♪◙}♪◙
```

А теперь шифрованая

```
D9 90 9B 3B EC 8E AE FB │ FD 57 35 3C AF A2 F8 6E
CC FA C7 33 41 8C 44 3A │ D3 14 E3 E2 37 C1 00 F3
B7 C4 54 1C 6A C2 91 C7 │ C2 BB D7 DE BD DB BA DA
6C 2E 2E 11 3D 42 30 A6 │ 47 90 F3 5F 46 54 01 14
0F D5 76 21 45 A3 46 3D │ AD E4 D1 59 3E 65 EC 5B
E6 E3 CA 06 8F 17 59 48 │ 66 01 35 D0 83 39 26 12
45 6C 5F 17 7E 6E 9D 76 │ 88 27 A5 76 23 56 3C F5
77 44 C0 C7 41 E2 FA F0 │ C5 8A B2 56 75 C6 E3 B1
7E 52 87 DB D5 3B 26 7E │ 25 55 A2 D7 40 E4 F4 83
96 F3 34 2C 2E 7F B2 15 │ F5 16 7E 8F 55 A7 32 F4
7C 39 BC 47 F5 B3 40 C7 │ 1D 7E B6 FE 5A D1 29 35
54 E8 3C 59 43 3B 54 28 │ 01 F6 DE E8 D8 36 F2 6A
67 09 2F 51 34 17 DD F9 │ EE 48 DE 71 B5 5E 5F 65
20 71 37 2E 89 40 13 BF │ CC 69 48 99 4B FB E6 94
CB 4A DA BD D9 DF E1 F6 │ E6 04 A5 B1 7B 90 CC DF
EC 2D 37 DB AB 6F 22 93 │ 20 23 C7 56 84 1B BF 3E
5F AF 3E 00 5C 1D 9B 0E │ 6C 27 04 A3 4F 0A 87 95
57 BE F1 81 D6 B1 93 46 │ 48 7D 75 88 2C 3B 8D BE
3A 08 32 EF A7 90 EC DD │ CE CA 5F 9D 8B 6B 95 20
10 1F 4F 71 CA 58 D7 0F │ 8A F9 B3 18 20 CA FA 2C
14 D4 90 DC 1D 41 58 EC │ 97 71 66 4B C2 F6 3C F5
77 36 12 78 92 C4 A2 70 │ 87 84 D2 D4 91 95 50 44
0A ED 7A 83 F8 24 77 49 │ 52 34 DA 50 30 6B 6F 44
A3 A3 76 D8 D3 2D 11 2E │ B2 3A BE 19 4C E1 34 13
12 31 47 2C 87 9B 73 83 │ D0 67 89 62 C1 3E 32 D6
75 9F DA 0E B0 40 5B EC │ 41 5C 21 D1 0F D1 E4 01
AE 76 E7 29 6F 91 4C 7E │ 12 03 19 A9 6C 79 80 39
3D 80 6B BC 43 AA 51 C9 │ 75 C5 D2 59 C1 57 8B 6D
84 C4 47 54 FC B2 48 E8 │ AF 4D C2 81 C7 44 AA 92
E9 5B 25 42 FA A0 63 35 │ 63 29 FC 68 F4 75 D0 C0
11 3F BA 70 7D AE 8B C2 │ 1C 1A 47 F7 C4 AE 84 B3
54 07 48 68 F4 DA 0A 28 │ B1 27 D1 0A 01 B4 41 AE
14 26 8C 36 5E A6 A6 86 │ 5C 34 DF 40 C5 C8 D4 0D
99 7F 92 13 90 E7 1A 4C │ 7A 8C 98 21 3C D3 69 0D
27 45 64 83 70 BE F0 A2 │ 8D 0C 51 89 C4 0B E2 24
C3 2A BC A7 BF C0 D4 F4 │ B8 82 DF 51 D3 C4 6A 14
5F 27 7A 37 30 DD D6 F4 │ 1B 3D 2E 5C 7A B2 EC 85
A9 23 9E 46 35 AE 44 48 │ 65 1C 14 1D 23 C5 45 4C
C6 61 E8 52 76 5C 8E 08 │ 62 83 8A 55 97 02 0D 03
EB BE 46 B4 4E 54 F0 3B │ A2 45 4D A7 44 C3 3E 4D
B8 AC BF 50 2B A9 07 DC │ C2 BE 31 79 B5 B1 2B CD
```

Файлы шифрованые от нешифрованых отличаются на 1-10 байт длинны без видимой зависимости (т.е. к-во дополнительных байт не зависит от длинны файла) (тут в примере на 5 байт в шифрованом больше). То уже думал просто xor обойтись, но пока не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: Перые c 0 по 0x1DF байты у design - файлов одинаковые, если в начале файла using три раза повторяется то 48 байт одинаковы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вирус *Petya* использует криптошифр [Salsa20](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) - это потоковый шифр с длиной ключа 256 бит, так просто его не расколотить, наличие образа до шифрования и после шифрования вам не поможет. Нормальные шифры уже давно умеют бороться с [known-plaintext-attack (KPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)

Salsa20 [не исключение](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8302/security-of-salsa20-with-some-known-plaintext)

Единственная надежда, но то что разработчики вируса сами писали реализацию криптоалгоритма, в результате [кое-где накосячили](http://blog.checkpoint.com/2016/04/11/decrypting-the-petya-ransomware/) и реализовали с ошибками. На основе этого [выпущен эксплойт ошибки](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/petya-ransomwares-encryption-defeated-and-password-generator-released/)

Не уверен, что это ваш случай.

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на правду. Шифрованые файлы имеют размер кратный 16 (а не 256), и вижу странность что одинаково-начинающиеся файлы различия в шифрованой версии показывают кратно 16 байт. это вначале меня наводило на мысли что разшифровать можно.

Comment: 256 бит = 32 байта и кстати, длина шифротекста не обязана быть кратной длине ключа...